# Aggregate X Into Count() is not accessible

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm looking at a solution that began life in .net Framework 2.0 and has now been moved up to Framework 4.0, so I'm probably missing a required reference and/or `Imports` line somewhere, I think...

I've got a LINQ query in the form:

```
Dim x = Aggregate myDataRow As System.Data.DataRow In myDataTable _
        Where (booleanCondition1) _
        AndAlso (booleanCondition2) _
        AndAlso (booleanCondition3) _
        Into Count()
```

I'm getting the compile error "`Definition of method 'Count' is not accessible in this context`".

As far as I can tell from [the literature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918069.aspx) the Count() function should be available (and apparently should register as a keyword).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've just changed my code to a straight Select method, like so:

```
Dim x = (From myDataRow As System.Data.DataRow In myDataTable _
        Where (booleanCondition1) _
        AndAlso (booleanCondition2) _
        AndAlso (booleanCondition3) _
        Select myDataRow)
```

and when I try to get the `.Count` of x, I get the message "`'Count' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)`" and [according to the MSDN, it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Totally confused, now.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and an import of `System.Data` as the documentation points to?

Comment: Or possibly `System.Core.dll` and import `System.Linq` if it's just using the Enumerable extension method.

Comment: I didn't have a `System.Data` Import, as it happens, but adding it doesn't seem to have helped. I've just been through to System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection in the object explorer and it doesn't seem to have any members at all... Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Do you have a reference to those assemblies?

Comment: `System.Linq` doesn't exist as a separate assembly any more, as I understand it (there's no reference for me to add), and trying to add a reference to `System.Core` brings up a MessageBox saying "This component is already automatically referenced by the build system."

Comment: What about `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I have that, too.

Comment: Imports and references are two different things. You can (and should) have an *import* of `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah. That fixed it. Any idea what's up with my object browser, then? I was assuming that the complete lack of any members to `EnumerableRowCollection(Of TRow)` was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at [`EnumerableRowCollection(Of TRow)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979.aspx), and note that `Count` is an extension method:

> `Count<TRow>()`   Overloaded. Returns the number of elements in a sequence. (Defined by [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).)

`Enumerable` itself has this information:

> **Namespace:**  System.Linq
> **Assembly:**  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

Note that you'll always find information on both assemblies and namespaces in the MSDN help. Both are important, and there's *not* a one-one correspondence between a type's namespace and the assembly that it's found in.

So, next, let's look at [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx). Unfortunately, it says this:

> Typically, the module in which an extension method is defined is not the same module as the one in which it is called. Instead, the module that contains the extension method is imported, if it needs to be, to bring it into scope

and then doesn't really elaborate fuller on what it means for the module to be in scope. It does *hint* at it towards the end though:

> When two extension methods that have identical signatures are in scope and accessible, the one with higher precedence will be invoked. An extension method's precedence is based on the mechanism used to bring the method into scope. The following list shows the precedence hierarchy, from highest to lowest.
>
> - Extension methods defined inside the current module.
> - Extension methods defined inside data types in the current namespace or any one of its parents, with child namespaces having higher precedence than parent namespaces.
> - Extension methods defined inside any type imports in the current file.
> - Extension methods defined inside any namespace imports in the current file.
> - Extension methods defined inside any project-level type imports.
> - Extension methods defined inside any project-level namespace imports.

Since the first two bullets aren't relevant to your situation, only the remainder apply. And they all deal with *imports*

[`Imports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx):

> The Imports  statement enables types that are contained in a given namespace to be referenced directly.

Hopefully, from all of the above, you can see why having a reference to the correct assembly, by itself, was insufficient, and you also needed to add an import.